# We need to Prove the existence or define a function on $[a, b]$

Tags: real-analysis

We need to Prove the existence or define a function on $[a, b]$ such that it is $n$ times differentiable but its $(n+1)$ th derivative is no where differentiable.

I have no idea how to start. was thinking about $|x|$ if $[a,b]=[-1,1]$

Comment: Take a continuous, nowhere differentiable function. Integrate ...

Comment: … e.g. take the [Weierstraß function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: so tough question for an exam!

Comment: Btw, $f(x) = \vert x \vert$ isn't differentiable. Well, $f^{(0)}$ exists, but $f^\prime(x)$ does not. The only problematic point is at $x = 0$ so it is not no where differentiable as it is differentiable everywhere else.